# How do i make my divs scrollable ONLY when the content is full?

Tags: php, html, css, scroll, scrollbar

i am making a group type page thing, and i have a div on the side of my webpage, which gets its members from the database, and so when there is like 5 members showing, i would like no scrollbars on the side but if the box fills up say with 15 members, i would like scrollbars to appear in the div box. I was wondering how is that achieved with html, css or php (simplest way possible).

Comment: Please post the relevant code here. Even better if you can provide an online example.

Comment: Define "full". Most site things are like, fluid/dynamic, or completely like fixed.

Comment: how about overflow:auto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever DIV you are using to contain this content make sure you change the **overflow** attribute to **auto** and then it is just a matter of making the height of the DIV tall enough so that it won't show a scroll bar when 5 peoples names are in the box, make it so when about 15 or so names are in the box it will be full therefore the scroll bar will automatically appear...

It should look something like this:

```
  .currentmembers{

width: 100px;
height: 500px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Using `overflow: scroll;` will also leave a horizontal scroll bar which I'm assuming you don't want so `overflow: auto;` will be the most appropriate. Also the height of your DIV will depend on the font sizes that the names will be in, the smaller the font size the more you will be able to fit in that one box before the scroll attribute comes into play.